# CountDownTimer Is Not Working In IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice, countdowntimer

I am using [wakefullintentservice](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) library.
So far it was working perfectly i used this library in many projects.

but know in my application i am using CountDownTimer Class.I don't know why it is not working.
i try to debug by it is not starting CountDownTimer code.
After calling **countDownTimer.start();**
nothing happened just released lock called.

Any Help Should Be Appreatied.
Thanks is advance.

Kindly i just want to do some work in IntentService With 1 Sec Delay.mean if it can be down without CountDownTimer Please Do Tell Me..

Here Is my code

```
public class AppService extends WakefulIntentService {
Context ctx;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
List<GCMessagingUtils> gcmessagelist;
public static final String Tag="AppService.java";
private long startTime;
int index = 0;
private final long interval = 1 * 1000;

public AppService() {
    super("AppService");
}

@Override
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
    Log.e(Tag, "doWakefulWork");
    OnAlarmReceiver.isSendingDataOn = true;
    ctx = getApplicationContext();
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(ctx);
    gcmessagelist = db.getAllGCMessages();
    startTime = gcmessagelist.size() * 1000;
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
    countDownTimer.start();

}

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        OnAlarmReceiver.isSendingDataOn = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Log.e(Tag,"Inside OnTick");
        if (index < gcmessagelist.size()) {
            GCMessagingUtils gcmessage = gcmessagelist.get(index);
            //Do Some Work
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Problem Solved:**

With The Solution Of [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink)

Hope It Will Help Some One.

I Just Place Looper.loop() in the end of doWakefulWork function So my code will look like this.

```
*
*
countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
countDownTimer.start();
Looper.loop() 
}
```

And in the CountDownTimer finish Quit The Looper

```
 @Override
public void onFinish() {
       OnAlarmReceiver.isSendingDataOn = false;
       Looper.myLooper().quit();
}
```

Comment: do you call Looper.prepare() somewhere?

Comment: no. i never used this what is this for?

Comment: In doWakefulWork method call Looper.prepare() in the beginning and Looper.loop() at the end

Comment: 10-02 13:49:16.646: E/AndroidRuntime(6372): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[AppService]
10-02 13:49:16.646: E/AndroidRuntime(6372): java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread
This is the error i am facing. after calling Looper.prepare() in the beginning and Looper.loop()

Comment: ok so add Looper.loop() only

Comment: in the beginning or end?

Comment: at the end, after CDT.start()

Comment: Looper.loop();
Log.e(Tag,"omg");
Brother this log msg nevers call mean.WakeLock Never Release Know What i do??

Comment: Looper.myLooper().quit(); thanks a lot thats how it now worked

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell this comes down to how an `IntentService` works. Basically when you start an `IntentService` it creates a worker thread which does whatever work it needs to do and then it will self-terminate.

In your code as soon as `doWakefulWork` exits then the `IntentService` will terminate. As a result your `CountDownTimer` will be terminated along with the `IntentService`.

Comment: Sir i know how intent service works.
But is not CountDownTimer is the part of his work it has to complete his task then terminate.
If not kindly do help me
please please
i want to place 1 sec sleep in this doWakefulwork Method.. Please any other solution..

Comment: @FahidMahmood: Do not use an `IntentService` (by putting your `CountDownTimer` in a regular `Service`) or do not use `CountDownTimer` (using `AlarmManager` instead).

Comment: So What should i do
Basically what i want to do is
When I will receive Sms I stored it into db.
After That i am running your library alarmmanger 5 sec 
to check if db has any msg or not
if yes then i call sendwakefullintent
And in this class as you can see above.
in CountDownTimer I am pulling each record and send to server. using AsyncTask
like This
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
PostDataAsyncTask pdat = new PostDataAsyncTask(ctx, gcmessage);
pdat.execute((Void[]) null);
}
This is my application what should i do if i am doing wrong??